# Razor variable and text without separator

Tags: razor

In webform this is possible:

```
<%: quantity %>x
```

If quantity is 2, it will display:

```
2x
```

In razor obviously I cannot do this:

```
@quantityx
```

Because it will then look for variable quantityx which doesn't exist.

Of course I can always do:

```
@(quantity.toString + "x")
```

But I want to know is there another way? Maybe there is a delimiter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
@(quantity)x
```

Comment: +1 Check out [Implicit and Explicit code nuggets with Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/16/asp-net-mvc-3-implicit-and-explicit-code-nuggets-with-razor.aspx) more detailed  informations.